# Current playing music file on cocosdenshion

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way or method to find out if there is any file playing on with simpleaudioengine and if there is some file already running then what is that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's guess you are using method

```
-(void) playBackgroundMusic:(NSString*) filePath;
```

the framework use for this method AVAudioPlayer which has a property "playing"
So you can easily write a method which return this BOOL property.